# Caching page based route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm trying to implement caching in my Rails application. A view in my controller generates a really large list of items based on a parameter passed in. This large list doesn't change very often, so I'd like to cache it based on the route.

**Example:**

config/routes.rb:

```
get "policies/available/:country" => 'policy#available', :format => :json
```

policy_controller.rb:

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController

  def available
    country = params[:country]
    @policies = VideoPolicy.available_in_country country
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json{
        render :json => @policies.to_json
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Calling "polices/available/US" would cache the JSON result for that route, then calling "polices/available/CA" would cache a *second* JSON result for that second route. (a.k.a. one result cached per-route, but for the same view/controller.)

How would I accomplish this? Some form of [page/action/fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Page caching might be what you're looking for.

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
  cache_page :available

  ...additional code...
end
```

When the available action gets hit, Rails will create a static JSON file in the public directory called `policies/available/US.json` assuming your route is `policies/available/US.json`.

Because there is now a file in the public directory matching the Rails route, the web server will hit the static file and missing the Rails app.

You can then expire the cache using `expire_page` after an update or create action. E.g.

```
def update
  @policy = VideoPolicy.find(params[:id])
  if @policy.update_attributes(params[:video_policy])
    expire_page "/policies/available/#{@policy.country}.json"
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return the JSON result for "policies/available/US" if "policies/available/CA" is called? (That would be a problem.) My data changes on based on the parameter, I don't want to return data that doesn't match the query.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I miss read the route in your question. I'll update the answer.